# Download content from div whilst on forloop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically i have an array that I'm looping over.
I display the results into my  container. What I'm trying to do is add a button; that downloads the most current text displayed inside div container. After researching I found out; the ::after element isn't apart of DOM hence my file was empty. How do I get around this?

```
<center><p>LOGS</p><center>
<a id="download_logs"></a>
<div id = "tags" class="editable">test</div>
```

Here when I download the file the letter 'test' comes, however not the items that are being looped.

Here is my "download_logs" button js part.

```
<script>
 function create_this(){
        var a = document.getElementById('download_logs')
        a.download = "export.text";
        a.href = "data:text/text," + 
        document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML;
        a.innerHTML = "[Export conent]";

      }
 window.onload=create_this();
 arr.forEach(function(data){

      console.log('this is data numbers', data.phone_number_attempted)
      results += '<br><span style="color:green;"> Message successfully sent to :' + data.phone_number_attempted + '</span>'
      $('.editable').html(results);
</script>
```

That is how I'm inserting my spans inside my tags container. Inserting works; it's just that when I download it on the mideway whilst loop the file is plain empty. I want to be able to download the current for loop items.